# Returning a value early from a recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

I have a tree of nodes. While iterating this tree depth first, I need to return the list of all duplicate nodes from the root node to my current node.

Due to some business requirements the "already traversed" part of the tree is never the same. I do a lot of swap/replaces of branches in the already traversed part of the tree. So maintaining a list of traversed nodes might not work as it needs updates every time I finish traversing a node.

So whenever I need to answer `getDuplicateNodesOfMyCurrentNode()` I need to start from the top of the tree (`rootNode`) and search depth-first till my `currentNode` and return back a `list<Nodes>` that are duplicates of my `currentNode`.

```
private void getDuplicateNodesOfMyCurrentNode(Node parentNode, Node currentNode,List<Node> dupNodes){
  for(Node child: parentNode.getChildren()){
        if(child == currentNode){
            return;
        }
        if(child.getApp().equals(currentNode.getApp()){
            dupNodes.add(child);
        }
        getDuplicateNodesOfMyCurrentNode( child, currentNode, aDupNodes);
```

}

As you guys already know the issue with this code, return doesn't return back the control to the caller of this API since it recursively calls itself. 
I want some way to exit out of this recursive loop once I get to my `currentNode`.

I probably can achieve this by maintaining some boolean state, but want to know the better way of solving this.

Comment: use break instead of return?

Comment: Nope that doesnt work.. Break only breaks out of the current call. I need to fall out of all the recursive calls

Comment: Return a boolean status (return true) and keep checking + dropping back until you hit the caller.

Comment: The method shown here is not recursive. It's a simple loop. What's the `builtOn` which is neither declared nor modified? btw.  Think of a another name for your method. A method `getDuplicateNodesOfMyCurrentNode` that returns `void` or even a `boolean` is not intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There was a typo in my java code. Modified it to make it recursive. Also yes , i would change the name of this method to make it more intuitive. Was just focusing to make sure that i make my self and my requirements clear here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass whether or not to abort your recursion back through the call stack via a boolean and abandon the current `for` loop if necessary at the point of the recursive call *(also acknowledging Norbet van Nobelen's comment above that alludes to something similar)*:

```
private boolean getDuplicateNodesOfMyCurrentNode(Node parentNode, Node currentNode,List<Node> dupNodes){
    for(Node child: parentNode.getChildren()){
        if(child == currentNode){
            return false;
        }
        if(child.getApp().equals(currentNode.getApp()){
            dupNodes.add(child);
        }
        if (getDuplicateNodesOfMyCurrentNode( builtOn, currentNode, aDupNodes) == false){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```